# How to prefetch javascript files based on es5/es2015 browser support

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have two scripts having same content, but one with **es5 standard code** and another with **es2015 standard code**.I want to **prefetch** one of this file based on browser support. With script tag we can instruct browser to ignore es5 files if browser supports es2015 standards by specifying **type='module'** for(es2015) & **nomodule** attribute. How can we do it with link tag?

```
<link rel="prefetch"  as="script" href="https://some-file-es5.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="prefetch"  as="script" href="https://some-file-es2015.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
```